# Access elements of a list in a yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I need to access and store a pod properties in kubernetes during creation. I can access to regular variables in the yaml without problem but i don't know (and could not find online) the syntax to access elements of a list.

```
apiVersion: "agones.dev/v1"
kind: GameServer
metadata:
  # generate a unique name
  # will need to be created with `kubectl create`
  generateName: ed- 
spec:
  ports:
    - name: game
      portPolicy: Dynamic
      containerPort: 7777
      protocol: UDP 
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ed-server
        image: myimage
        imagePullPolicy: Always # add for development
        command: ["sh", "-c"]
        args:
          - echo MY_ID=$(MY_ID)\nMY_IP=$(MY_IP)\nMY_PROTOCOL=$(MY_PROTOCOL)\n";
        env:
          - name: MY_ID # THIS WORKS FINE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: MY_IP # THIS WORKS FINE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          #- name: MY_PROTOCOL # THIS FAILS
          #  valueFrom:
          #    fieldRef:
          #      fieldPath: spec.ports[0].protocol
```

I will like to know the correct syntax and get some proper documentation source on the topic.

EDIT: I've put the actual yaml i'm using after requested. I'm using agones framwork but the question is generic. If the parser knows how to access a literal and a dictionary it should be able to access an array.

Thanks!

Comment: this is not a valid pod resource, can you please share the actual resource you are trying to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your YAML isn't a valid one. Seems like you've Frankensteined both `Deployment` and `Pod` YAMLs.

Your YAML should  look like below:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: foo
        image: dummy_image:0.0.1
        ports:
        - name: game
          portPolicy: Dynamic
          containerPort: 7777
          protocol: UDP
```

**Answer:**

Unfortunately, the `ports` field is not supported by the `fieldRef`.
Check [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api) for the supported field list.

Since the port information doesn't change dynamically on the pod runtime, you can export it like this:

```yaml
    env:
    - name: MY_PORT
      value: "game"
```

Comment: I see. There is a way to access that data at runtime?. Maybe with a variable and use of expressions?

Comment: I don't know such ways. But If you implement the `kube-client` inside your program, with proper RBAC permissions, you can get the whole Pod YAML.